# Figure title with several colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to have multiple font colors in matplotlib figure titles? Something like this
[image: three colors in the title]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following snippet seems to work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
fig1.text(0.45, 0.95, "Case A", ha="center", va="bottom", size="medium",color="red")
fig1.text(0.5, 0.95, "&", ha="center", va="bottom", size="medium")
fig1.text(0.55,0.95,"Case B", ha="center", va="bottom", size="medium",color="blue")
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

As far as I can see the title generated by matplotlib title function only contains one text object and hence can only have one font color. This is the reason for making multiple text elements on the figure.

Answer (score 8):

One can also use `figtext()` command of matplotlib, like below,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
    plt.plot(x, np.sin((i+1)*x),'r')
    plt.plot(x, np.cos(4*x/(i+1)),'b')
    plt.title('(i+1)='+str(i+1))

plt.figtext(0.47, 0.96, "Case A", fontsize='large', color='r', ha ='right')
plt.figtext(0.53, 0.96, "Case B", fontsize='large', color='b', ha ='left')
plt.figtext(0.50, 0.96, ' vs ', fontsize='large', color='k', ha ='center')
plt.show()
```