# Add 2 main titles to matplotlib figure with different fontsizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with 2 subplots. I want 2 main titles for the whole figure above these plots with different fontsizes. So this is not about getting titles above the ax but in the figure part.

I know I can add a main title (suptitle) to a figure by using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 8))

fig.suptitle('This is my 1st main title', x=0.5, y=1.15, fontsize=18)
```

But I want another:

```
fig.suptitle('This is the second with other fontsize', x=0.5, y=0.98, fontsize=12)
```

But this just overwrites the first.

How can I get two main titles? (or 1 main title and 1 subtitle)

[image: Figure with one main title, how add a subtitle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just found out, one possible solution is to not use fig.suptitle() but to use fig.text():

```
fig.text(s='This is my 1st main title', x=0.5, y=1.00, fontsize=18, ha='center', va='center')
fig.text(s='This is my 2nd main title', x=0.5, y=0.95, fontsize=12, ha='center', va='center')
```

This post pointed me in the right direction: [Figure title with several colors in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350171/figure-title-with-several-colors-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Great solution.. Works like a charm ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `text()` function. You can either link it to the figure:

```
f.text(x=0.5, y=0.94, 'title', ha='center')
```

You can use the following arguments that are quite straightforward:

```
rotation='vertical'
fontsize=10
```

You could also link the title to a subplot, and use the X, Y of this subplot to position it:

```
ax[0].text(0, 1.02, "title above the first subplot", fontsize=10, transform=ax[0].transAxes)
```

And finally, you might need to redefine the dimension of the plotting area. This can be done with:

```
for a in f.axes:
    # Shrink the axes
    box = a.get_position()
    a.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.9, box.height * 0.95])
```