# How can I add a title for a subgroup of subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, subplot

I'm trying to create a subplot group with two title levels. One for the individual graphs and one for each peer.

Unfortunately I can't get the following configuration.

[image]

I am looking to add titles A and A.

I tried to add a subplot within a subplot and give a title to the two rungs in the hierarchy, but it seems that it is impossible.

Here is my current code:

```
fig.set_size_inches(16, 2.5)
for i, df in enumerate([df3,df12,df5, df6]):
    axes[i].set_title(title[i])
    if i != 3:
        df.plot(x='x',y='y',color= 'red', ax =axes[i],alpha=0.9, legend= None)
    
    else:
        df.plot(x='x',y='signal',color= 'red', ax =axes[i],alpha=0.9)
        axes[i].legend(loc="lower right", ncol=2, labels =["y"], fontsize=12)
plt.savefig(title[i]+'.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186903/15521392) help maybe?

Comment: Maybe use subfigures. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html