# How to manipulate properties of variable which is passed by string in suptitle?

Tags: python, variables, matplotlib, suptitle

I was wondering if I can manipulate properties of variable `{count}` after string in suptitle to change variable's color, location(by printing in next line center) and font size.

So far I can print it out like this in middle above of picture:

> Analysis of data in cycle Nr.:0000

```
 plt.suptitle(f'Analysis of data in cycle Nr.: {count}', color='yellow', backgroundcolor='black', fontsize=48, fontweight='bold')
```

Any ideas or trick to access to variable properties?
I expect output would be like below :

> Analysis of data in cycle Nr.:
>   0000 (diffrenet color and font size)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Figure title with several colors in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350171/figure-title-with-several-colors-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use suptitle for that. use fig.text(x,y,"Text", args)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(0,0, 'Some Text', color='red')
fig.text(0.2,0.95, 'superDuperCool:', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
fig.text(0.45,0.95,'9001', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', color='green')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
ax.set_title('axes title')
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')    
ax.plot([2], [1], 'o')
ax.annotate('annotate', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 4),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
ax.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])

plt.show()
```